# How to show that $\|T_+^k\|=\|{T_+}\|^k$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I try to prove that $$\|T_+^k\|=\|T_+\|^k$$

where $T_+$ is a bounded linear operator: $T_+:l^\infty\longrightarrow l^\infty$

and

$$T_+(x_1,...x_n,...)=(0,x_1,...,x_n,...)$$

$$||{T_+^k}||=||{T_+}||^k$$ since we have:

$$||{T_+^k}||=||{T_+T_+^{k-1}}||=\frac{||{T^+}||\cdot||{T_+^k}||}{||{T_+}||}$$

and since

$$||{T_+^k}||\leq||{T_+}||^k$$

we further have that : $$||{T_+^{-1}}||^{-1}=||{T_+}||$$, since $T_+$ is bijective. Therefore

$$||{T_+^k}||=||{T_+}||^k$$

We then prove that $T_+$ is bounded, by

$$||T_+x||\leqslant c||x||$$

where $c$:

$$\frac{||T_+x||}{||x||}\leqslant c$$

and for $$c=||T||$$ we get:

$$||Tx||\leqslant ||T||\cdot||x||$$

Therefore, by the norm we obtain:

$$\underset{x_n\in\mathscr{D}T_+}{sup}||{T_+^kx}||=\underset{x_n\in\mathscr{D}T_+}{sup}||{T_+x}||^k$$

But is this sufficient?

Comment: For starters, don’t fix a finite $n$ to take your metric over when the domain has infinite dinension

Comment: Is there a reason why you call your operator $T_+$ and not simply $T$? Also, shouldn't you add some extra hypothesis?

Comment: For example, what would happen if your operator was nilpotent?

Comment: added more infom

Comment: Yes, in general, when asking questions about a particular operator it is a good idea to give the definition of said operator  :)

Comment: I would suggest, first show it is bounded. Then the same idea can be used to prove the assertion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First show $T_+$ is indeed a bounded operator:

$$
\Vert T_+ x \Vert = \Vert (0,x_1,x_2,\ldots) \Vert = \Vert x\Vert. 
$$

So $\Vert T_+\Vert =1$. But the same reasoning applies to $T_+^k$:

$$
\Vert T_+^k x \Vert = \Vert (0,\ldots,0,x_1,x_2,\ldots) \Vert = \Vert x\Vert. 
$$

So  $\Vert T_+^k\Vert =1= \Vert T_+\Vert^k$.

Comment: Simple and nice. Thanks

Comment: You're very welcome

Comment: When $T_+$ is an isometry then $T_+^k$ is an isometry for any $k.$ So the formula for $T^k_+$ for $k\ge 2,$ is not needed.